# where vs. find(). What is a recommendation for their use?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In what situations should be used Model.where or Model.find() ? Everywhere is information on the differences, but what is a recommendation for their use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`where` doesn't actually fetch anything - it returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` scoped with the conditions you've just specified. This means you can chain it with stuff: more calls to `where`, `joins`, `limit` etc.

`find` on the other can executes the query and returns an array or an object (depending on whether you do `find :all` or `find :first`, so you can't chain stuff on the back of it.

You can pass conditions, joins etc. to find but doing so will become deprecated. You don't really ever need to call `find` since you either let the `ActiveRecord::Relation` turn itself into an array when it needs to or call `all`/`first`/`last` on the relation, which achieves the same thing that calling `find` would do.

About the only thing `find` is handier for is when you have an id (or array of ids) and want to load the corresponding model objects.

Answer (score 1):

We use `find` any time there's only a single result that must be visible for the page to be useful. E.g. `/item/:id`. We rescue NotFound exceptions and then show a 404 error page if that's caught.

When it's possible for there to be a missing item, we use `where`, and `first` if it makes sense.